# Boto: Unable to install on CentOS

Tags: python, boto

so i have been trying to install boto on CentOS . I have installed python 2.6 using this steps

```
    sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.6/Python-2.6.6.tgz
     tar -zxvf Python-2.6.6.tgz
     cd Python-2.6.6
./configure && make && make install

python --version
Python 2.6.6
which python 
/usr/local/bin/python
```

after which i installed

```
sudo yum install python-pip
```

and then boto

```
python-pip install boto
```

But when i do import boto , I get error 
**ImportError: No module named boto**
Can anyone help ?
PS: when i do

```
sudo pip install -U boto
```

It says 
Requirement already up-to-date: boto in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: Can you post the content of pip binary file? You can see it by executing `cat $(which pip)`. May be pip uses different python.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python2

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())

Answer (score 0):

Your pip uses python located at `/usr/bin/python2`, but you use `/usr/local/bin/python`.

If you don't need in using python 2.6 just uninstall it. Then check that `python` binary is pointed to `/usr/bin/python2` and try to run your script again. It should work.

If you need to use python 2.6 I think the easiest way is to uninstall `python-pip` package and then install `pip` using `get-pip.py` script according to [this](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py) manual. After installing check that output of `cat $(which pip)` consists the right version of python (`/usr/local/bin/python` in your case). Then reinstall `boto` using newly installed `pip`. After that I think all should work.

P.S. Unfortunetely I can't check precisely if this will work because I don't have install CentOS.

Comment: I am completely new to python . Can you tell me what should i do here?

Comment: Is it necessary for you to use python 2.6 or you can use newer version from CentOS repository?

Comment: will python 2.6 cause any problem ? to use newer verison of Python do i have to uninstall existing python 2.6?

Comment: It is old version of python and as I understand some python packages doesn't support it already. Also I think that python 2.7 is already installed in your system (I can't say precisely because I never use CentOS).

Comment: If you can use python 2.7 no doubt you should use it. It is not necessary to uninstall python 2.6 but it would be easier for you to do it.